# Using a HashMap to store database table & column names

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, resultset

I have some code that retrieves table & column names from a database:

```
PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SQLUser'");
rs = p.executeQuery();
```

I was thinking that I could use a HashMap to store this data, where the key is the table name (which is always unique) and an ArrayList to store the list of columns contained within that table.

How can I iterate through the ResultSet so that for each table a new ArrayList is created, populated with related column names and then added to the HashMap using that table name as the key?

Comment: *I have some code that retrieves table & column names ...* Add it to the question then.

Comment: @Manu Please find that I added the code that retrieves the data, however I didn't include it in the first place because it adds nothing to the question as it only adds the results to the ResultSet rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);        
while (rs.next()) { 
    String table = rs.getString("table_name"));
    ArrayList<String> columns = map.get(table);
    if (columns == null) {
        columns = new ArrayList<String>();
        map.put(table, columns)
    }
    columns.add(rs.getString("column_name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this -

```
Map<String, List<String>> tableMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();

PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SQLUser'");

ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    String columnName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));
    columnList.add(columnName);
}                   
tableMap.put("SQLUser", columnList);
```

Also you can use the ResultSetMetaData to get the column names from a table.

```
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("Select * from SQLUser")
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
int count = metaData.getColumnCount(); 
List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
   columnList.add(metaData.getColumnLabel(i))); 
}
```

Comment: sqluser is a schema. there are maybe hundreds of tables in a schema